# get Average of column in one to many Relation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I Have 2 table:

`stores
store_feedbacks | store_id , user_id ,rating`

rating is number between 1-5 , Now I want to get average of all rating for one store,How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your relationships are correctly set up:

```
$store->ratings()->avg();
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#aggregates - they're from the queries page, but it applies to Eloquent as well.